# AOSP AOSP x86_64 XCB

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

I have troubles after download AOSP x86_64

emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))

Do u have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

did you run the command through remote ssh connection?
try with `--no-window` command option or run the command in desktop terminal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31210581)